# Why are the axios cookie response headers different in the browser and in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I used `axios` to call the API to get the cookie value in React(using `Create React App`).

When I opened the browser's developer tools and checked the axios response header in the console, there was no `set-cookie` property.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lQOc.png)

I opened the browser's developer tools and checked the Cookies from the Application and found that the cookie was stored.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQinM.png)

On the other hand, when I opened a terminal and called the API using axios in Node.js and checked the response header of axios, the `set-cookie` property was present there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGJkD.png)

I want to run axios in React (browser) and get the cookie value, but
I don't know why the `set-cookie` property disappears in the browser.
Why the difference between the two (browser and Node.js)?

Below is the environment and source code where I ran it.

## Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- browser: Google Chrome Version 106.0.5249.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Node.js 16.13.0
- react-scripts 5.0.1
- axios 0.27.2

## Code

### App.tsx (run in browser)

```
import "./App.css";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";

function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const options: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      url: "/cookie",
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
    };

    axios(options).then((resp: AxiosResponse) => {
      console.log(resp.headers);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Cookie</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Supplementation

I used Create React App and set `proxy` to `package.json` to avoid CORS errors in API requests

```
// package.json
{
 ...
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ...
 },
 ...
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

### index.js (run in Node.js)

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getCookie = () => {
  const options = {
    url: "http://localhost:8080/cookie",
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
  };

  axios(options)
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.headers);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};

getCookie();
```

- I ran `node index.js` in a terminal

### server.go (API that returns a cookie)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func cookieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, "Method is not supported", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Set-Cookie")

    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "sampleName",
        Value:    "sampleValue",
        HttpOnly: false,
        Path:     "/",
    })
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello")
}

func main() {
    
    http.HandleFunc("/cookie", cookieHandler)

    fmt.Printf("starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: check the network tab in the browser tools - you'll see all the headers there

Comment: @JaromandaX
Thanks for your comment.
Yes, I could see the `set-cookie` in the network tab as well. But I want to get the `axios` response (`resp.headers["set-cookie"]`　in `App.tsx`).

Comment: why? the cookies are all( * ) available in `document.cookies` - why do you think you need to access the set-cookie header in a browser? ( * ) all meaning the ones that are not http-only, of course, otherwise http-only cookies would be meaningless if they were available in `document.cookies` - if you want to get the cookies from `set-cookie` because you need to know more than just the value of the cookie, then, you're using cookies for the wrong reason